# regexp_replace Unicode in PostgreSQL

Tags: regex, postgresql, unicode

How to regexp_replace for Unicode in PostgreSQL

i read this http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html

```
select regexp_replace('s4y8sds', '\\p{Number}', '')
```

or

```
select regexp_replace('s4y8sds', '\\p{N}', '')
```

but not work

i have this following code work in PHP

```
preg_replace( "/[^\p{Ll}|\p{Lm}|\p{Lo}|\p{Lt}|\p{Lu}|\p{Zs}]/u", "", "string1212.," );
```

Please help me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For ordinary numbers use `digit` character class as `[[:digit:]]` or shorthand `\d`:

```
SELECT regexp_replace('s4y8sds', $$\d+$$, '', 'g');
```

Result:

```
 regexp_replace
----------------
 sysds
(1 row)
```

For other numbers (for example ¼) is not that simple, more precisely as [documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-matching.html#POSIX-BRACKET-EXPRESSIONS) says it's ctype (locale) dependent:

> Within a bracket expression, the name of a character class enclosed in
>   [: and :] stands for the list of all characters belonging to that
>   class. Standard character class names are: alnum, alpha, blank, cntrl,
>   digit, graph, lower, print, punct, space, upper, xdigit. These stand
>   for the character classes defined in ctype. A locale **can** provide
>   others.

However you could use internal PL/Perl procedural language and write server-side function with wanted Unicode characters classes `\p{}`:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION removeNumbersUnicode(text)
RETURNS text AS $$
    $s = $_[0];
    $s =~ s/\p{N}//g;
    return $s;
$$ LANGUAGE plperl;
```

Check [Chapter 41](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plperl.html) from doc for more info how to write such functions.

Comment: owh, i c. So i must use plperl, and can't directly use \p{N} in regexp_replace ? Thanks

Comment: @Thessa: Yes, `\p{N}` syntax isn't supported with `regexp_replace`. There are more procedural languages, even [PL/PHP](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/external-pl.html) if you want, but `PL/Perl` seems to best candidate for such issue.

Comment: I'm getting error :
createlang: language installation failed: ERROR:  could not load library "C:/Pro
gram Files (x86)/PostgreSQL/9.0/lib/plperl.dll": The specified module could not
be found.

Comment: i fix the language installation issue. Thanks so much Grzegorz Szpetkowski