# Unicode regexp_replace in PostgreSQL

Tags: regex, postgresql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [regexp_replace Unicode in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6992529/regexp-replace-unicode-in-postgresql)

How to regexp_replace for Unicode in PostgreSQL

i read this http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html

```
select regexp_replace('s4y8sds', '\\p{Number}', '')
```

or

```
select regexp_replace('s4y8sds', '\\p{N}', '')
```

but not work

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know Postgres does not understand \p{} (as in the article you have linked).
See the docs here http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/functions-matching.html

According to this answer, [internationalized regular expression in postgresql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3820034/internationalized-regular-expression-in-postgresql/3820313#3820313) Unicode is not supported by Postgres in this way.

In case you want to replace numbers with empty string, you can do it like this:

```
select regexp_replace('s١4y8sd½s', '[0-9١٢٣¼½¾]', '', 'g');
 regexp_replace 
----------------
 sysds
```

Comment: I'm working with Unicode. so if i have number in other format like Roman(Ⅱ Ⅲ Ⅳ), Arabic(١ ٢ ٣ ٤) and Other(¼ ½ ¾). regexp_replace('s4y8sds', E'\\d+', '', 'g') cant work

Comment: @Thessa, thanks for clarifying your question. I'll update the answer in a minute.